# Flutter Parse Server Sdk not saving the second object in the table (class)

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

this function takes a ServicePoint object as argument, which has the following attributes:

- adminId (String)
- name (String)
- serviceType (enum)

I want this function to create a new Table with name: "name+adminId". This is achieved.
Also I want this function to create a new Table (if it is not there already) by the name ServicePoints.
ServicePoints stores the relationship between user (with objectId = adminId) and the new Table.
To achieve this, I set "serviceTable" attribute with value as the new Table created, acting as a pointer.

When I run the code first time, I achieve the required tables. But, when I run the function second time, it doesn't add the new row/record to ServicePoints table.
I don't know why.

**UPDATE** I found that set ParseObject operation is the culprit. But, to my surprize, it executes successfully for the very first time. But fails every next time. This is really absurd behaviour from parse_server_sdk_flutter.

```
Future<bool> createServicePoint(ServicePoint servicePoint) async {
    String newServicePointName = servicePoint.name + servicePoint.adminId;
    var newServiceTable = ParseObject(newServicePointName);
    var response = await newServiceTable.save();
    if (response.success) {
      print('Now adding new row to ServicePoints table');
      var servicePointsTable = ParseObject('ServicePoints')
        ..set<String>("serviceName", servicePoint.name)
        ..set<String>("adminId", servicePoint.adminId)
        ..set<String>("serviceType", _typeToLabel[servicePoint.serviceType])
        ..set<ParseObject>("serviceTable", newServiceTable);
      var recentResponse = await servicePointsTable.save();
      return recentResponse.success;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: If anyone wishes to run, I can share the test code on github, to reproduce the error. Plz help me out.

Comment: when you save for the first time, Parse Server learns from your fist saved object and creates the column `serviceType` as a Pointer to the new class you've just created with name `servicePoint.name + servicePoint.adminId`. All following requests must set to the `serviceType` column only objects that belong to this class. Objects of any other class will fail. That's probably your problem.

Comment: Ohh, I see. May be that's the case. Thanks for your insight @DaviMacêdo

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this problem, you need to check the result after saving the ParseObject. If there is error like "Can't save into non-existing class/table", then just go to the dashboard and create the table first.